# MS Access - WHERE IN works, but WHERE NOT IN fails

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query (simplified) on MS Access:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT table1id FROM table2);
```

My problem is it doesn't work, but these two ones work:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT table1id FROM table2);
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID NOT IN (2, 3);
```

The first one simply returns me an empty set, while I know I have records on `table1` with ids ranging from 1 to 9, and only 2 and 3 are use on table 2.

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by 'works' and 'fails'?  Perhaps show some data to explain.

Comment: How does it fail or not work?

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*? Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify the issue. @Gordon Linoff's solution worked pretty well though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, the problem with IN and NOT in has to do with NULLs in the subselect.  Try this and see if it works:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT table1id FROM table2 where tableid is not null);
```