# ACCESS 2010 SQL-- using WHERE IN on SELECT TOP subquery field

Tags: sql, select, subquery, ms-access-2010, where-clause

I want this query to tell me the spending in 2012 of the companies who were the top 10 spenders in 2013!

```
SELECT [Company], 
       Sum([SPENDING])
FROM   [Data]
WHERE  [Company] IN (
                     SELECT TOP 10 [Company]
                     FROM          [Data]
                     WHERE         [Year] IN ("2013")
                     GROUP BY      Company
                     ORDER BY      Sum([SPENDING]) DESC
                     )
       AND [Year] IN ("2012")
GROUP BY Company
;
```

When I try to run it, I get no errors, but Access says it is "running query" and never finishes. The size of the data is not the problem.

This is the closest example I found, but it doesn't really give light to the answer: [MS Access - WHERE IN works, but WHERE NOT IN fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376816/ms-access-where-in-works-but-where-not-in-fails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that this is just a limitation of Access's optimizer.  Try it like this instead:

```
SELECT d.[Company], 
       Sum(d.[SPENDING])
FROM   [Data] As d
INNER JOIN    (
                     SELECT TOP 10 [Company]
                     FROM          [Data]
                     WHERE         [Year] IN ("2013")
                     GROUP BY      Company
                     ORDER BY      Sum([SPENDING]) DESC
              ) As t  ON  t.Company = d.Company
WHERE d.[Year] IN ("2012")
GROUP BY d.Company
```

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks very much for the new form. When I try to run this in Access though, I get "Syntax Error in FROM clause" and I can't seem to fix it

Comment: Yep, sorry. I forgot that Access doesn't tolerate as many abbreviations as SQL Server does.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: @JRob How long does it take?

Comment: it takes about 1 second

Comment: @JRob Cool!  Thanks for letting us know.