# IN works, but NOT IN does not

Tags: ms-access

First, I first read this: [MS Access - WHERE IN works, but WHERE NOT IN fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376816/ms-access-where-in-works-but-where-not-in-fails)

However, the solution isn't working for me.  My issue is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MOVIE.Movie_Num, MOVIE.Movie_Title, 
MOVIE.Movie_Year, VIDEO.Movie_Num
FROM MOVIE INNER JOIN VIDEO ON MOVIE.Movie_Num = VIDEO.Movie_Num
WHERE (((MOVIE.Movie_Num) In (SELECT Movie_Num from VIDEO)));
```

This works as it should.  There's one Movie_Num that doesn't show up in VIDEO, so it doesn't show up in the query.

However, when I try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MOVIE.Movie_Num, MOVIE.Movie_Title, 
MOVIE.Movie_Year, VIDEO.Movie_Num
FROM MOVIE INNER JOIN VIDEO ON MOVIE.Movie_Num = VIDEO.Movie_Num
WHERE (((MOVIE.Movie_Num) Not In (SELECT Movie_Num from VIDEO)));
```

It doesn't display any records when there should be one.

Is there something in the syntax I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your INNER JOIN is filtering the "missing" record so the where clause doesn't matter.

Comment: Wouldn't the INNER JOIN be automatic since the tables are linked?  I'm not sure how to fix that.  (We only just started into SQL)

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  Remove the VIDEO table :D.  

Thanks.